# Trouble scraping data rows - beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Beginner working with python and beautiful soup, attempting to scrape election results data from a state elections page. Went by the book 'learning to code with baseball' to learn all of my basics, including the 5th chapter which covers scraping.

I am working on scraping one table from the site, which looks like this:

| Candidate | Total Votes | Pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abraham Lincoln | 53990 | 42.1% |
| George Washington | 37326 | 29.1% |

After using BeautifulSoup to read the entire site and identify the tables. I was successful in isolating this table from the rest of the tables on the site and identifying the header row using:

```
gov_table = tables[3]
rows = gov_table.find_all('tr')
header_row = rows[0]
```

The trouble i ran into was with the data rows. I cannot seem to pick up the candidate's names, only their 'total votes' and 'pct'.

I try:

```
first_data_row = rows[1]
first_data_row.find_all('td')
```

which gives the HTML:

```
[<td class="candidate" data-title="Candidate" scope="row">ABRAHAM LINCOLN <span class="smalltext">(DEM)</span> </td>,
 <td class="number mail-in" width="25%">
 <ul class="mailinbreakout">
 <li>Polling place: 51771</li>
 <li>Mail ballots: 2219</li>
 </ul>
 </td>,
 <td class="number total votes" data-title="Total votes">53990</td>,
 <td class="number total percent" data-title="Pct">42.1%</td>]
```

I then attempt to run a comprehension on all the td tags to isolate them in a list, which I will use as the rows to a DataFrame. But the trouble I have is, I cannot seem to pick up the candidates name:

```
In [82]: [str(x.string) for x in first_data_row.find_all('td')]
Out[82]: ['None', 'None', '53990', '42.1%']
```

I'm really stumped about the 'None' strings as they dont appear anywhere in the table rows themselves. I have tried narrowing in on it further using

```
In [83]: [str(x.string) for x in first_data_row.find_all('td', {'scope': 'row'})]
Out[83]: ['None']
```

or

```
In[87]: first_candidate_name = first_data_row.find_all('td')[0]
...first_candidate_name
...str(first_candidate_name.string)
Out[87]: 'None'
```

With similar results.

I am sure I am missing something relatively minor but my beginning eyes can't narrow it down.

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: https://www.ri.gov/election/results/2014/statewide_primary/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.string` to access the content within the rows, and some of these rows have multiple children, which means `.string` will return `None`

On the other hand, `.get_text()` returns all the strings of the children concatenated into one string

```py
> [str(x.string) for x in first_data_row.find_all('td')]
> ['None', 'None', '53990', '42.1%']
```

```py
> [str(x.get_text()) for x in first_data_row.find_all('td')]
> ['Gina M. RAIMONDO (DEM) ', '\n\nPolling\xa0place:\xa051771\nMail\xa0ballots:\xa02219\n\n', '53990', '42.1%']
```

From the [documentation:](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

> **.string**
>
> 1. If a tag has only one child, and that child is a NavigableString, the child is made available as .string:
> 2. If a tag’s only child is another tag, and that tag has a .string, then the parent tag is considered to have the same .string as its child:
> 3. If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None:

> **.get_text()**
> If you only want the human-readable text inside a document or tag, you can use the get_text() method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string:

Comment: This is what I was hoping to hear, because I suspected that it had to do with the str(x.string) piece. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you resolve the conundrum. Let me know if something is not clear.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.ri.gov/election/results/2014/statewide_primary"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

table_5 = soup.find_all('table')[5]
trs = table_5.find_all('tr')
tds = trs[1].find_all('td')
print(tds[0].text)
print(tds[2].text)
print(tds[3].text)
```

Output

```
Nellie M. GORBEA (DEM)
58444
51.4%
```

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful for being printing out results for individual tables, but i still need to be able to run a comprehension so that, for every candidate in a table, I can print a list in the form ['Nellie M. Gorbea (DEM), '58444', 51.4%]. So taking your code and running: [str(x.string) for x in table_data] still returns a list of ['None', 'None', '53990', '42.1%'].

Comment: The other answers point out why you should be using .text rather that .string.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop the h3 within the results to get the positions/titles and use find_next to get the adjacent tables. Add the position to each table, read into a df using pandas, add each table to a list to turn into a single dataframe at the end with pd.concat. You can also extract, for example, the party from the candidate.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.ri.gov/election/results/2014/statewide_primary/#"
page = requests.get(url, headers = {'user-agent':'mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
dfs = []

for position in soup.select('.results h3'):
    title = position.a.text
    df = pd.read_html(str(position.find_next('table')))[0]
    df.loc[:, 'Title'] = title
    dfs.append(df)
    
final = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 0)
final[['Candidate','Party']] = final['Candidate'].str.split(pat = ' \(|\)', n = 2 , regex= True, expand=True).iloc[:, :-1]
final[['Polling place', 'Mail ballots']] = final['Ballot breakout'].str.split(pat = '[\W\s]+', regex= True, expand=True).iloc[:, [2,5]].astype(int)
final = final[['Title', 'Party', 'Candidate', 'Total votes', 'Pct', 'Polling place', 'Mail ballots']].sort_values(['Title', 'Party', 'Total votes'], ascending = [True, True, False])
final.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

---

**Sample result rows:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition, simplest approach would be to use `pandas.read_html()` that works with `BeautifulSoup` under the hood and is best practice to scrape table data.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat(pd.read_html('https://www.ri.gov/election/results/2014/statewide_primary/#'), ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

|  | Candidate | Ballot breakout | Total votes | Pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John F. REED (DEM) | Polling place: 94157 Mail ballots: 4453 | 98610 | 100.0% |
| 1 | David N. CICILLINE (DEM) | Polling place: 36220 Mail ballots: 1966 | 38186 | 63.0% |
| 2 | Matthew J. FECTEAU (DEM) | Polling place: 21637 Mail ballots: 810 | 22447 | 37.0% |
| 3 | James R. LANGEVIN (DEM) | Polling place: 42740 Mail ballots: 1772 | 44512 | 100.0% |
| 4 | Gina M. RAIMONDO (DEM) | Polling place: 51771 Mail ballots: 2219 | 53990 | 42.1% |

...

---

Or using `get_text()`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.ri.gov/election/results/2014/statewide_primary/#"
res = requests.post(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

data = []
for tr in soup.select('div.raceResults table tbody tr'):
    d = [t.get_text(' ',strip=True) for t in tr.select('td')]
    del d[1]
    data.append(dict(zip(['Candidate','Total votes','Pct'],d)))

pd.DataFrame(data)
```